# Gradle/Eclipse - Add projects to the classpath

Tags: eclipse, gradle

In my Eclipse workspace, I have two projects, projectA and projectB. projectA is in a different folder from projectB (separate git repositories, not near each other on the file system). Is there any way for gradle to apply projectB to the classpath of projectA using the gradle plugin for eclipse?

**Project A's build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
dependencies {
    compile 'myorg:projectB:+'
}
```

**Project B's build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'

publishing {
    publications {
        ivy(IvyPublication) {
            organisation 'myorg'
            module 'projectB'
            revision '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
            descriptor.status = 'integration'

            configurations {
                archive {} 
            }

            from components.web
        }
    }
    repositories {
        ivy {
            url "/path/to/repo"
            layout "pattern", {
                ivy "[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[module]-[revision].xml"
                artifact "[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact](-[classifier])-[revision].[ext]"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could manually do this by manipulation the ```eclipse.classpath.afterMerge``` or ```eclipse.classpath.withXml``` but I guess this is not what you want?